# is there a way to fix this error regarding list indexes?

Tags: python

I am trying to swap two indexes of a list accessed by entering a command followed by two numbers corresponding to the indexes that i would like to swap with each other, however it returns an error (at bottom of the page)

Is this because of the fact that the list does not contain strings /  integers ?
Does this require me to transform the string part of the command output (the commands themselves) to integers?

Following my code:

```
todo_list = []


#command that manages all of the user inputs, jurisdicting the specific key words being allocated with the specific functions associated with it
#whilst blocking out the rest of the data thats entered that does not begin with a tag. (e.g. random stuff.)

def parse_command(cmd):
    arg = cmd.split()
    if arg[0] == 'add':
        add_item(arg[1])
    elif arg[0] == 'remove':
        remove_item(arg[1])
    elif arg[0] == 'mv':
        move_item(arg[1], arg[2], todo_list)
    elif arg[0] == 'ls':
        list_items()
    else:
        print("not a valid command")
    
    
def add_item(item):
    for i in range(0, 1):
        tasks = item
        todo_list.append(tasks)
    print("Your to-do list so far: ", todo_list)
    
def remove_item(idx):
    #removal message
    print("successfully removed todo-list entry position #{}".format(idx)) 
    #remove by index
    todo_list.pop(int(idx))
    
    
def move_item(idx1, idx2, todo_list):
    #swap message 
    print("successfully swapped list position #{} with #{}".format(idx1,idx2))
    #swapping list indexes
    todo_list[int(idx1)], todo_list[int(idx2)] = todo_list[int(idx2)], todo_list[int(idx1)]
    return (int(todo_list))

def list_items():
    for x in range(len(todo_list)):
        return todo_list[x]
                
while(True):
    
    cmd = input("Please input command: ")
    parse_command(cmd)
```

When I input `mv 0,3` to `Please input command:` , I get the following error:

```py
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-751618dd832b> in <module>
     51 
     52     cmd = input("Please input command: ")
---> 53     parse_command(cmd)
     54 
     55 

<ipython-input-105-751618dd832b> in parse_command(cmd)
     13         remove_item(arg[1])
     14     elif arg[0] == 'mv':
---> 15         move_item(arg[1], arg[2], todo_list)
     16     elif arg[0] == 'ls':
     17         list_items()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: ``mv 0,3`` are *two* items: ``mv`` and ``0,3``. Your code assumes *three* items – ``mv``, ``0`` and ``3``. Use a space instead of a ``,`` as the separator in your input.

Comment: "is this because of the fact that the list does not contain strings/ integers?" No; it's because the *index is out of range*, like the error tells you. Do you understand what an index is? Do you understand what "out of range" means? (if not, did you try putting that [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=out+of+range)?) Do you understand what the range ought to be for `arg` at that point in your code? Did you try checking the length of `arg`? Was it what you expected?

Comment: "Please input command: `mv 0,3` ... and below this is the error it spits out when i type `mv 0 3`" You need to be more precise when describing problems. Those are two different inputs that should not be expected to behave the same way.

Comment: how am i able to pass the argument so that it swaps the indexes over in the list then? any ideas? cause ive been trying to do this for like 2 hours now loll

Comment: As a rule, always check you have the correct number of arguments **before** you check them - i.e. `if len(arg) >= 3` (or handle the IndexError)

Comment: where would i put this in my code? id assume in parse_command(cmd)?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

Firstly, by entering **'mv 0,3'** you are entering **two** arguments, not three. If you want to access these arguments, you will need to split the second argument (by a comma).

The below will fix that issue, **HOWEVER** this is not the only issue:

```
def parse_command(cmd):
    arg = cmd.split()
    #try:
    if arg[0] == 'add':
        add_item(arg[1])
    elif arg[0] == 'remove':
        remove_item(arg[1])
    elif arg[0] == 'mv':
        args = arg[1].split(',')
        print(args)
        move_item(int(args[0]), int(args[1]), todo_list)
    elif arg[0] == 'ls':
        list_items()
    else:
        print("not a valid command")
    #except IndexError:
        #print("Usage: <Command> <arguments>")
```

I have deliberately left the error handling commented, and the inner block unindented, so you can see the remaining issues with your code.

Changing the **move_item** function to the following:

```
def move_item(idx1, idx2, todo_list):
    #swapping list indexes
    todo_list[idx1], todo_list[idx2] = todo_list[idx2], todo_list[idx1]
    print("successfully swapped list position #{} with #{}".format(idx1,idx2))
    
    return (todo_list)
```

This will throw another `IndexError` when you input the command `mv 0,3`, as the list `todo_list` is empty. You either need to make sure that the indexes provided to `move_item` are in range, or handle the `IndexException` that is thrown when they aren't.

I would suggest passing the list to alter into the `parse_command` function, to make it clear which list you are trying to alter. I would then either check that the indexes in `args` are in the range of the list passed to `move_item`, or handle any `IndexError` thrown by `move_item`.